# Memory Usage for Dijkstra's Algorithm in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memory, dijkstra

I've been learning Haskell as I find the language to be expressive, and to practice it, a friend has been giving me problems from Codeforces to do. The current problem I've been working on is to [implement Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://codeforces.com/contest/20/problem/C).

Below is a snippet of the algorithm (and [here is the full code](https://github.com/milkywayw/dijkstra-haskell/blob/main/Dijstkra.hs)):

```
type Edge = (Node, Distance)

type Route = [Node]

type Graph = Map Node [Edge]

-- tracking which nodes we've gotten to
type VisitedNodes = Set Node

-- set will be used as a priority queue, along with prev/curr nodes
type PriorityQueue = Set (Distance, (Node, Maybe Node))

-- on the optimal path from start to end, what's the preceding node for a given node?
type PreviousMap = Map Node Node

-- to declutter the function types
type DijkstraStructs = (VisitedNodes, PriorityQueue, PreviousMap)

dijkstra :: Graph -> Node -> DijkstraStructs -> Maybe PreviousMap
dijkstra graph target (visitedNodes, pq, prev)
  | emptyPrioQueue = Nothing
  | alreadyVisited = dijkstra graph target (visitedNodes, nextPq, prev)
  | reachedTarget = Just nextPrevMap
  | otherwise = dijkstra graph target (updatedVisitedNodes, neighborPq, nextPrevMap)
  where
    -- we've exhausted the search along the nodes we can reach when this is true
    emptyPrioQueue = Set.null pq

    -- greedy: find the edge leading to the tentatively closest node, and remove it
    ((distance, (nearestNode, maybePrevNode)), nextPq) = Set.deleteFindMin pq
    updatedVisitedNodes = Set.insert nearestNode visitedNodes

    -- if the current node has been visited already, we will skip
    alreadyVisited = nearestNode `Set.member` visitedNodes

    -- for path-tracking
    nextPrevMap = case maybePrevNode of 
      Nothing -> prev
      Just prevNode -> Map.insert nearestNode prevNode prev

    -- if the nearest node is the target node, then we're done. the path is encoded in the PreviousMap
    reachedTarget = nearestNode == target

    -- otherwise, keep searching. add all outgoing edges from current node into priority queue
    neighbors = (Map.!) graph nearestNode
    neighborPq = foldr (\(toNode, w) -> Set.insert (distance + w, (toNode, Just nearestNode))) nextPq neighbors
```

I believe my implementation of the algorithm is correct, but I suspect it's memory inefficient, as my submissions to Codeforces exceed the memory limit for large inputs (e.g., 50k nodes // 100k edges -- my algorithm uses more than 64MB on such a case).

While my immediate goal is to iterate on my algorithm in order to successfully submit it, my longer term goal is to learn how to reason about the memory usage of Haskell code in general.

I suspect a large portion of memory might be attributed to "versioning" of the intermediate Sets and Maps, but I am not sure how to think about the impact of "mutating" (i.e., creating new versions) of immutable data structures in Haskell.

In an attempt to profile my code, I followed a procedure I found [on this site](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/09/detecting-space-leaks.html), which helped me detect and fix a stack overflow from using foldr for large inputs, but sadly I haven't been able to use this approach to measure the memory usage of the algorithm itself.

I would love to learn how to optimize the memory usage of this code, as well as learn how to profile/measure and reason about memory usage in Haskell. Improvements to this code, as well as general stylistic feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem to worry about is space leaks. When is each argument of your `dijkstra` function forced?

`graph` and `target` are constant. `visitedNodes` is forced by the `alreadyVisited` guard. `pq` is forced by the `emptyPrioQueue` guard. But there is nothing to force `prev`, so it gets thunked: the `case` expression of `nextPrevMap` is delayed until the very end of the whole execution, when the final `PreviousMap` is evaluated. So you have a chain of thunks that is about as long as the number of visited nodes.

Comment: Thanks for this insight -- seems like a good way to avoid large thunks. I have amended the program to have BangPatterns, and have placed a bang pattern on the `prev` parameter in `dijkstra`. Sadly, this doesn't seem to affect the heap size for this algorithm and I am still experiencing a large amount of memory used for this!